# Backbone.js pattern in Require.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

Without using Require.js, I sturcutre my app like this:

```
window.App = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Routers: {},
    Views: {},
    init: function(){
        App.router = new App.Routers.main();
        Backbone.history.start();
    }   
};

$(function() {
    App.init();
});
```

But now i've started using Backbone.js and I am wondering what's the best to to implement the pattern above in it. More specifically, is it 'good practise' to assign to window object the App? And in the above example, we are basically creating a global reference. Is this also common in Require.js? If not, what's the alternative pattern in Require.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check those links  http://kilon.org/blog/2012/08/build-backbone-apps-using-requirejs/
                         https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/philip-kedy/modularizing-your-backbone-router-using-requirejs

It should help .

Bye!